# How to merge 2 dataframe rows in a new dataframe row with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 variables (dataframes) one is 47 colums wide and the other is 87, they are DF2 and DF2.
Then I have a variable (dataframe) called full_data. Df1 and DF2 are two different subset of data I want to merge together once I find 2 rows are equal.

I am doing everything I want so far besides appending the right value to the new dataframe.

below is the line of code I have been playing around with:

```
full_data = full_data.append(pd.concat([df1[i:i+1].copy(),df2[j:j+1]].copy(), axis=1), ignore_index = True)
```

once I find the rows in both Df1 and DF2 are equal I am trying to read both those rows and put them one after the other as a single row in the variable full_data. What is happening right now is that the line of code is writting 2 rows and no one as I want.

what I want is full_data.append(Df1 DF2) and right now I am getting

```
full_data(i)=DF1
full_data(i+1)=DF2
```

Any help would be apreciated.
EM

```
full_data = full_data.append(pd.concat([df1[i:i+1].copy(),df2[j:j+1]].copy(), axis=1), ignore_index = True)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a little tour on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), also important to provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74586298/edit) your question with some example data and its desired output.

Comment: Here is a good post with everything about [merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: If both rows are **equal** - why do you want the rows one above the other - they will be the same ? Surely it would make more sense just to keep one of them ??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved my problem. Probably I was not clear enough but my question but what was happening when concatenating is that I was getting duplicated or multiple rows when the expected result was getting a single row concatenation.

The issues was found to be with the indexing. Indexing had to be reset because of the way pandas works.

I found an example and explanation [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-combine-data-in-pandas-5-functions-you-should-know-651ac71a94d6)

My solution here:

```
df3 = df2[j:j+1].copy()
df4 = df1[i:i+1].copy()

full_data = full_data.append(
    pd.concat([df4.reset_index(drop=True), df3.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1),
    ignore_index = True
)
```

I first created a copy of my variables and then reset the indexes.